# CsvHelper error when using RegisterClassMap

Tags: c#, csv, generics, .net-core, csvhelper

I've based the mappings for my CSV file based off the official docs
here: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started

here are my class I'm using

```
public class DropShippperCSV
{
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseNumber { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryCompanyTrackingNumber { get; set; }
}

public class DropShippperCSVMap : ClassMap<DropShippperCSV>
{
    public DropShippperCSVMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.PurchaseOrderNumber).Column("Delivery Company Tracking Number");
        Map(m => m.ReleaseNumber).Column("Release Number");
        Map(m => m.LineNumber).Column("Line Number");
        Map(m => m.DeliveryCompanyName).Column("Delivery Company Name");
        Map(m => m.DeliveryCompanyTrackingNumber).Column("Delivery Company Tracking Number");
    }
}
```

then calling on it like so

```
                var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader);

                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DropShippperCSVMap>();
               var records = csv.GetRecords<DropShippperCSV>().ToList();
```

and I'm getting this error

> Error   CS0311  The type 'DropShippperCSVMap' cannot be used as type parameter 'TMap' in the generic type or method 'IReaderConfiguration.RegisterClassMap()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DropShippperCSVMap' to 'CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap'.

I've based directly off the offical docs and I can't tell what I did wrong

Comment: Could you try with _Map(m => m.PurchaseOrderNumber).Name("Delivery Company Tracking Number");_ ?

Comment: @Steve what do you mean by that? I'm not sure what yo want me to change

Comment: Instead of Column I have a mapping using the Name property

Comment: @steve that did the trick, I dropped the FluentNHibernate and RegisterClassMap entirely and used CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes instead. those docs need work

Answer (score 20):

Use `csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DropShippperCSVMap>();` instead of `csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DropShippperCSVMap>();`.

Answer (score 1):

I droped FluentNHibernate and RegisterClassMap entirely and used CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes Name attribute to do the mapping instead